# How to fix "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SOL_UDP'" error in Python Connector Mule

Tags: mule, mule-esb, jython-2.7, mulesoft, ciscoconfparse

I'm trying to execute a basic script to return Cisco Config File as a JSON Format, and I have a success process over Python2.7.16 and Python 3.7.3, but when I'm trying to execute the same script over Python Connector for Mule ESB I receive the error refered in the title of this thread.

This is for a Mule feature, the Python connector script in this tool, works with a Jython 2.7.1, and is loaded as a library for the Mule.

I expect the output as a JSON file but actual output is:

```
Root Exception stack trace:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<script>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ciscoconfparse\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ciscoconfparse import *
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ciscoconfparse\ciscoconfparse.py", line 17, in <module>
    from models_cisco import IOSHostnameLine, IOSRouteLine, IOSIntfLine
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ciscoconfparse\models_cisco.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ccp_util import _IPV6_REGEX_STR_COMPRESSED1, _IPV6_REGEX_STR_COMPRESSED2
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ciscoconfparse\ccp_util.py", line 16, in <module>
    from dns.resolver import Resolver
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\dns\resolver.py", line 1148, in <module>
    _protocols_for_socktype = {
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SOL_UDP'
```

Comment: Talk to the dns.resolver project if you don’t get your answer here.  FYI ciscoconfparse has nothing to do with the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: resolver.py]

The only thing I had to do was comment that line in the script resolver.py and in this way the script on Anypoint Studio ran smoothly.

Thanks for your help, I hope that this helps to other people.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that you are trying to execute a script that depends on a different python package. Mule supports executing python scripts using the Java Jython implementation but it probably doesn't know about pyhton packages dependencies.

Comment: Thanks Alejandro, I finally found a solution, I had to comment the line of the library where that parameter was requested, which made the Anypoint flow work without problem, now I have problems to deploy in cloudhub, I do not know in which path the library should load ciscoconfparse for that can read it from cloudhub.

Comment: You don't have any access to install libraries in CloudHub. You should package everything that the application needs in the application, for example in the src/main/resources directory or a jar library. Otherwise it will not be accessible to it.

Comment: Thanks Alejandro, I have an example with the ciscoconfparse library running success over cloudhub, Thanks :)